# How to access iframe in PHP Scriptable Web Browser

Tags: php, iframe

I am using [PHP Scriptable Web Browser](http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html)  for downloading some data from 
one web site and that website contains so many links https://www.xxxx.com/CWRWeb/ReportNav.do?rid=CHARGEBACK using this link i want to download the data this page contains one iframe when is access this page using my script i am able to get the that page contain but not able to get `iframe` content from that page

can any one guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, we will need more information to answer the question

Comment: Is any other way to solve this problem ?